# Problem with initializing value to the variable

Tags: python, class

I am trying to understand one part of code which I came across , but I can not come up with an idea, how it was programmed.

What I have a main problem with is a variable wbe, which has a default value None. And in the next part of the code, it is trying to reach an atribute (x), which these varibale does not even have.

I have added derived class (WeibullEstimator) and also a parent classs (Estimator).

This is main part of code:

```py
class WeibullEstimator(Estimator):
 def __init__(self, n_alpha_predictors, n_rho_predictors, wbe=None, report_interval=100):
        super().__init__()
        self.n_alpha_predictors = n_alpha_predictors
        self.n_rho_predictors = n_rho_predictors
        self.report_interval = report_interval
        self.counter = 0

        # Initialize parameters
        self.x = np.zeros(2 + n_alpha_predictors + n_rho_predictors)
        if wbe:
            self.x[0] = wbe.x[0]
            self.x[1 + self.n_alpha_predictors] = wbe.x[1 + wbe.n_alpha_predictors]
        else:
            self.x[0] = -0.01

        self.alpha = None
        self.rho = None
```

and the Estimator class is progammed here:

```py
class Estimator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None

    def evaluate(self, alpha_x, rho_x):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def save(self, file_path):
        np.save(file_path, self.x)

    def load(self, file_path):
        self.x = np.load(file_path)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: so what is the issue here?

Comment: I don't see, how can i reach an x atribute of the variable wbe, if it doesnt have any.

Comment: there is `if condition` there. where during object intitalization ie `obj=WeibullEstimator( n_alpha_predictors, n_rho_predictors)` is done this way then `self.x[0] = -0.01` is set . if  `obj=WeibullEstimator( n_alpha_predictors, n_rho_predictors,wbe=<data - here>)`  is done  `        if wbe:
            self.x[0] = wbe.x[0]
            self.x[1 + self.n_alpha_predictors] = wbe.x[1 + wbe.n_alpha_predictors]` this part of the code is run. so when when  wbe is intialise , then this if true part run

Comment: If you don't pass wbe parameter into "WeibullEstimator" class constructor, then constructor will not even try to touch it. You have in __init__ method "if wbe: something; else: something else not touche wbe". if condition "if wbe:" just check it if wbe is not None.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your quick response.